# efficiency and speed in image processing with FPGA

Tags: fpga, vhdl, speed, synthesis, imageprocessing

Hi I have been writing a code in VHDL for some image processing. However, due to some reasons I have not yet determined the sythesis does not stop. I suspect that efficiency of the code is not as much as I need it to be, which slows down the process of sythesis. I am new to hardware world and still learning. I am using Basys3 board and Vivado2017.2 environment. My computer is not old and works fine in terms of speed/power. How can I reduce sythesis time and reach a result??

Code is complex I am aware but it will get more complex because extra features will be added. What I do is moving a frame on the picture and depending on the operation chosen changing pixels inside the frame.

Here is the code I wrote

```
        library IEEE;
        use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
        use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;
        use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
        use std.textio.all;


        entity vga_core is
        generic (
        PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT : integer := 250;
        COLOR_BIT : integer := 4);
        port (
        default_clk : in  std_logic := '0';
        rst     : in  std_logic:= '0';
        data_r  : out std_logic_vector(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0);
        data_g  : out std_logic_vector(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0);
        data_b  : out std_logic_vector(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0);
        hs_out  : out std_logic;
        vs_out  : out std_logic;
        operation : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        mode: in std_logic;
        go_left : in std_logic;
        go_right: in std_logic;
        go_down: in std_logic;
        go_up: in std_logic;
        enable : in std_logic;
        cursor_mode : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
        );
        end vga_core;

        architecture VGA of vga_core is

        ---------------------------------------------------------
        ---------CONSTANTS FOR VGA-------------------------------
        ---------------------------------------------------------

        constant RES_H         : integer := 640;
        constant RES_V         : integer := 480;
        constant H_FRONT_PORCH : integer := 16;  
        constant H_SYNC_TIME   : integer := 96;
        constant H_BACK_PORCH  : integer := 48;
        constant V_FRONT_PORCH : integer := 11;  
        constant V_SYNC_TIME   : integer := 2;
        constant V_BACK_PORCH  : integer := 31;
        constant TOTAL_H       : integer := RES_H + H_FRONT_PORCH + H_SYNC_TIME + H_BACK_PORCH; -- 800
        constant TOTAL_V       : integer := RES_V + V_FRONT_PORCH + V_SYNC_TIME + V_BACK_PORCH; -- 524 

        ---------------------------------------------------------

        constant LENGTH_1      : integer := PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT;
        constant LENGTH_2      : integer := 10;
        constant LENGTH_3      : integer := 25;
        constant LENGTH_4      : integer := 50;

        signal length : integer range 0 to PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT := LENGTH_1;

        ---------------------------------------------------------
        ----------------Signals used for VGA operations ---------
        ---------------------------------------------------------

        signal COUNTER_H : integer range 0 to TOTAL_H := 0; -- 0 to 800
        signal COUNTER_V : integer range 0 to TOTAL_V := 0; -- 0 to 524
        signal NEW_LINE  : std_logic := '0';
        signal h_visible : std_logic := '0';
        signal v_visible : std_logic := '0';
        signal visible   : std_logic := '0';

        ---------------------------------------------------------
        ------------------Clock things---------------------------
        ---------------------------------------------------------

        signal clk : std_logic := '0';
        signal temporal: std_logic := '0';
        signal counter : integer range 0 to 1 := 0;

        ---------------------------------------------------------
        --------Upper-left positions of the frame----------------
        ---------------------------------------------------------

        signal cursor_pos_x : integer range 0 to PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT := 0;
        signal cursor_pos_y : integer range 0 to PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT := 0;

        ---------------------------------------------------------
        ----------Positions of the pixels on the screen----------
        ---------------------------------------------------------

        signal pos_x   :  integer range 0 to 2047 := 0;  
        signal pos_y   :  integer range 0 to 2047 := 0;

        ---------------------------------------------------------

        signal vgaData :  std_logic_vector(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) := "000000000000";

        type RamType is array(0 to PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT - 1, 0 to PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT - 1) of bit_vector(11 downto 0);

        --My ram is 2-dimensional by the way

        impure function InitRamFromFile (RamFileName : in string) return RamType is
        FILE RamFile : text is in RamFileName;
        variable RamFileLine : line;
        variable RAM : RamType;
        begin
        for y in 0 to 249 loop
        for x in 0 to 249 loop
        readline (RamFile, RamFileLine);
        read (RamFileLine, RAM(x,y));
        end loop;
        end loop;
        return RAM;
        end function;

        signal RAM : RamType := InitRamFromFile("\\ASUS\Users\AsusPc\Desktop\project_son\pictureData.data");

        begin

            -- according to cursor mode, length is adjusted

            with cursor_mode select length <=
            LENGTH_1 when "00",
            LENGTH_2 when "01",
            LENGTH_3 when "10",
            LENGTH_4 when "11";

            --I obtain a clock signal with 25Mhz frequency

            CLOCK_DIVIDER: process (default_clk) begin

            if rising_edge(default_clk) then
                if (counter = 1) then
                    temporal <= NOT(temporal);
                    counter <= 0;
                else
                    counter <= counter + 1;
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;

        clk <= temporal;

        ---------------------------------------------------------
        --------------VGA THINGS---------------------------------
        ---------------------------------------------------------

        CNT_H : process (clk) is
        begin  
        if clk'event and clk = '1' then
          if (COUNTER_H = TOTAL_H-1) then
            COUNTER_H <= 0;
            NEW_LINE  <= '1';
          else
            COUNTER_H <= COUNTER_H + 1;
            NEW_LINE  <= '0';        
          end if;
          end if;
        end process CNT_H;

        CNT_V : process (clk) is
        begin  

        if clk'event and clk = '1' then
          if (NEW_LINE = '1') then
            if (COUNTER_V = TOTAL_V-1) then
              COUNTER_V <= 0;          
            else
              COUNTER_V <= COUNTER_V + 1;
            end if;
          end if;
        end if;
        end process CNT_V;

        SYNC_H : process (clk) is
        begin  

        if clk'event and clk = '1' then
          if (COUNTER_H < H_SYNC_TIME) then
            hs_out <= '0';
          else
            hs_out <= '1';
          end if;
        end if;
        end process SYNC_H;

        SYNC_V : process (clk) is
        begin  

        if clk'event and clk = '1' then
          if (COUNTER_V < V_SYNC_TIME) then
            vs_out <= '0';
          else
            vs_out <= '1';
          end if;
        end if;
        end process SYNC_V;

        AREA_H : process (clk, rst) is
        begin  

        if clk'event and clk = '1' then
          if (COUNTER_H > H_SYNC_TIME + H_BACK_PORCH - 1) and (COUNTER_H < TOTAL_H - H_FRONT_PORCH) then
            h_visible <= '1';
            if ((COUNTER_H - (H_SYNC_TIME + H_BACK_PORCH)) <641) then
            pos_x <= COUNTER_H - (H_SYNC_TIME + H_BACK_PORCH);
            end if;
          else
            h_visible <= '0';
          end if;
        end if;
        end process AREA_H;

        AREA_V : process (clk) is
        begin  

        if clk'event and clk = '1' then
          if (COUNTER_V > V_SYNC_TIME + V_BACK_PORCH - 1) and (COUNTER_V < TOTAL_V - V_FRONT_PORCH) then
            v_visible <= '1';
            if ((COUNTER_V - (V_SYNC_TIME + V_BACK_PORCH)) < 481) then
            pos_y <= COUNTER_V - (V_SYNC_TIME + V_BACK_PORCH);
            end if;
          else
            v_visible <= '0';
          end if;
        end if;
        end process AREA_V;

        visible <= h_visible and v_visible;

        --------------------------------------------------------------
        --------------------------------------------------------------
        --------------------------------------------------------------

        --Used to move the frame to left

        GOING_LEFT: process (go_left, clk) is
        begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
        if go_left = '1' then
        if (cursor_pos_x - length - 1 > 0) then
        cursor_pos_x <= cursor_pos_x - length  - 1;
        else
        cursor_pos_x <= 0;
        end if;
        end if;
        end if;
        end process GOING_LEFT;

        --Used to move the frame to right

        GOING_RIGHT: process (go_right, clk) is
        begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
        if go_right = '1' then
        if (cursor_pos_x + length  - 1 < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) then
        cursor_pos_x <= cursor_pos_x + length  - 1;
        else
        cursor_pos_x <= PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT - 1;
        end if;
        end if;
        end if;
        end process GOING_RIGHT;

        --Used to move the frame up

        GOING_UP: process (go_up, clk) is
        begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
        if go_up = '1' then
        if (cursor_pos_y - length  -1 > 0) then
        cursor_pos_y <= cursor_pos_y - length  - 1;
        else
        cursor_pos_y <= 0;
        end if;
        end if;
        end if;
        end process GOING_UP;

        --Used to move the frame down

        GOING_DOWN: process (go_down,clk) is
        begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
        if go_down = '1' then
        if (cursor_pos_y + length - 1 < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT)  then  
        cursor_pos_y <= cursor_pos_y + length  - 1;
        else
        cursor_pos_y <= PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT - length ;
        end if;
        end if;
        end if;
        end process GOING_DOWN;

        --------------------------------------------------------------
        --------------Most important part----------------------------
        --------------------------------------------------------------


        SHOW : process (clk, rst) is
                begin   

                if rising_edge(clk) then --clk
                if rst = '1' then --rst

                RAM <= InitRamFromFile("\\ASUS\Users\AsusPc\Desktop\project_son\pictureData.data");

                cursor_pos_x <= 0;
                cursor_pos_y <= 0;

                elsif (visible = '1') and ( pos_x < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) and (pos_y <PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) and (pos_x > -1) and (pos_y > -1) then

                if((pos_y = cursor_pos_y) and ((pos_x > cursor_pos_x -1) or (pos_x < cursor_pos_x + length ))) or ((pos_y = cursor_pos_y + length -1) and ((pos_x > cursor_pos_x -1) or (pos_x < cursor_pos_x + length))) then --drawing the frame part 1
                        vgaData <= "000000000000"; --black
                        data_r <= vgaData(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT);
                        data_g <= vgaData(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT);
                        data_b <= vgaData(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0);       

                elsif ((pos_x = cursor_pos_x) and ((pos_y > cursor_pos_y - 1) or (pos_y < cursor_pos_y + length))) or ((pos_x = cursor_pos_x + length -1) and ((pos_y > cursor_pos_y - 1) or (pos_y < cursor_pos_y + length))) then --drawing the frame part 2
                        vgaData <= "000000000000"; --black
                        data_r <= vgaData(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT);
                        data_g <= vgaData(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT);
                        data_b <= vgaData(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0);
                else       
                        vgaData <= to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y));
                        data_r <= vgaData(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT);
                        data_g <= vgaData(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT);
                        data_b <= vgaData(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0);
                end if;

                if ((pos_x > PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT - 1) and (pos_y > -1)) or ((pos_y > PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT - 1) and ((pos_x > -1) or (pos_x < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT))) then
                        vgaData <= "000000001111"; -- blue
                        data_r <= vgaData(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT);
                        data_g <= vgaData(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT);
                        data_b <= vgaData(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0);

               end if;
               end if;
               end if;

               end process SHOW;

               --Whenever cursor_mode changes, cursor positions are reset

               ADJUSTING_cpx_and_cpy: process(cursor_mode) is
               begin

               cursor_pos_x <= 0;
               cursor_pos_y <= 0;

               end process;


               BRIGHTNESS: process(enable,clk) is

               begin

               if rising_edge(clk) then
               if enable = '1' then
               if operation = "00" then
               if ( pos_x > cursor_pos_x - 1) and (pos_x < cursor_pos_x + length) and ( pos_y > cursor_pos_y - 1) and (pos_y < cursor_pos_y + length) then -- condition

               if mode = '0' then 

               if to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x, pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT)) < 14 then
               RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) <= to_bitvector(to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT)) + 2);
               end if;

               if to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT)) < 14 then
               RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) <= to_bitvector(to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT)) + 2);
               end if;

               if to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0)) < 14 then
               RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) <= to_bitvector(to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0)) + 2);
               end if;

               elsif mode = '1' then 

               if  to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT)) > 1 then
               RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) <= to_bitvector(to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT)) - 2);
               end if;

               if  to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT)) > 1 then
               RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) <= to_bitvector(to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT)) - 2);
               end if;

               if to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0)) > 1 then
               RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) <= to_bitvector(to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0)) - 2);
               end if;   

               end if; --mode

               end if; --condition

               end if; --operation
               end if; --enable
               end if; --clock

               end process BRIGHTNESS;

              CONTRAST: process(enable, clk) is
              begin
              if rising_edge(clk) then
              if enable = '1' then
              if operation = "01" then
              if (pos_x > cursor_pos_x - 1) and (pos_x < cursor_pos_x + length) and ( pos_y > cursor_pos_y - 1) and (pos_y < cursor_pos_y + length) then -- condition

              if mode = '0' then                   

              if   to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT)) < 8 and  to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT)) > 1 then

              RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) <=  to_bitvector(to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT)) - 2); 

              elsif  to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT)) > 7 and to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT)) < 14 then

              RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) <=  to_bitvector(to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT)) +2) ;
              end if;

              if   to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT)) < 8 and  to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT)) > 1 then

              RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) <=  to_bitvector(to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT)) - 2);

              elsif  to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT)) > 7 and  to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT)) < 14 then

              RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) <=  to_bitvector(to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT)) +2) ;
              end if;

              if   to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0)) < 8 and  to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0)) > 1 then

              RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) <=  to_bitvector(to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0)) - 2);

              elsif  to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0)) > 7 and  to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0)) < 14 then

              RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) <=  to_bitvector(to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0)) +2) ;
              end if;

              elsif mode = '1' then                    


              if  to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT)) < 8 and to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT)) > 2 then

              RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) <= to_bitvector(to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT)) - 3);

              elsif to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT)) > 7 and to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT)) < 13 then

              RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) <= to_bitvector(to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT)) +3) ;
              end if;

              if  to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT)) < 8 and to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT)) > 2 then

              RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) <= to_bitvector(to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT)) - 3);

              elsif to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT)) > 7 and to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT)) < 13 then

              RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) <= to_bitvector(to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT)) +3) ;
              end if;

              if  to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0)) < 8 and to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0)) > 2 then

              RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) <= to_bitvector(to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0)) - 3);

              elsif to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0)) > 7 and to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0)) < 13 then

              RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) <= to_bitvector(to_stdlogicvector(RAM(pos_x,pos_y)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0)) + 3) ;
              end if;

              end if; --mode

              end if; --condition

              end if; --OPERATION
              end if; --ENABLE
              end if; --CLK

              end process CONTRAST;



        end VGA;
```

This code unfortunately did not get me anywhere.

Comment: Very long synthesis in Vivado can be related to many causes. One of them is poor understanding of design constraining. Your code seems to be something you put together along without much testing (sorry that is the feeling). If you are new to VHDL coding you should build your foundations: Start with much smaller code, learn how to code not only to solve your problem but also for your synthesizer being able to produce reasonably sized hardware. That does not happen overnight, you need to start with small steps.

Comment: Experienced designers create small blocks of code that are later on integrated together. That makes easier to mantain and cooperate. Your code is impossible to see even for yourself.

Comment: I see a loop some where with total = 250x250 = 62500 iterations. It will infer huge hardware probably slowing down synthesis.

Comment: You should strategically divide huge design to modules, synthesis it to verify, then integrate it, synthesis again.

Comment: I've never worked with Xilinx's tools, but I'd be very concerned that that 2D array of `bit_vector`s might synthesize as latches rather than RAM, which might be your issue.  Have you tried it with a smaller size to see if the correct element type is selected?  I'd suggest instead using a standard predefined RAM module and calculating addresses (probably by concatenating bits, so you get a 256*256 array, rather than using a multiplier to get 250*250 - this may be a little inefficient in RAM space but is likely to save a lot more in the way of addressing logic, and you have the RAM to spare).

Comment: @MeenieLeis, when a "for loop" of 62000 is used, the tool will try to instantiate 62000 copies of "readline" and "read" hardware blocks, probably with 62000:1 multiplexors each or something, with is likely impossible and insane from the tool view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before embarking on something like VGA output and "image processing", I would strongly advise to start with simple things first, to make sure your clocks are getting into logic blocks, and outputs are connected properly and configured  / mapped.

Start with a simple n-bit counter, such that the MSB is toggling at 1 second rate. And connect this output to any available LED on the developer board. In this way you will learn the synthesis-map-routing process, if it works and how it works.

For a VGA project, proceed with a simple buffer, fill it with some pattern, and get your VGA row/column scan process to output proper signals to the VGA port, ensuring all necessary timing. No "image processing" or cursor generation/movement.

Only if you master these basic things, you may begin developing "image processing" blocks on the top of this buffer.

Comment: I did that and I am able to show picture on screen. I know basics and how vhdl works. Thanks

Comment: @Onur From what you code we understood you know basics of c/c++. But not VHDL. For eg: you use nasty loops in your code, incomplete combinational processes which infer latch, Too many nested ifs, no hardware modularity, etc.

Comment: @OnurTR, apparently you don't understand the concept of Hardware Description Language, and FPGA in general. Listen to comments on your "code".